# Exponential Markov Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I need to show that:
$$
P[\alpha X\geq \epsilon]\leq\frac{E[e^{\alpha X}]}{e^\epsilon} , \epsilon>0
$$
Does this work the same way as the normal Markov-Inequality? Because with that way I couldn't really figure out the solution, I mean this way:
$$
E[e^{\alpha X}]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\alpha X}f(x)dx=...
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\alpha X \geq \epsilon$ iff $e^{\alpha X} \geq e^{\epsilon}$. Hence $P(\alpha X \geq \epsilon)=P(Y \geq e^{\epsilon}) \leq \frac {EY} {e^{\epsilon}}$ where $Y=e^{\alpha X}$.

Comment: But for $Y=e^{\alpha X}$ the exponential function has to be measurable right? So I have to show that too...

Comment: Any continuous function from the real line in to itself is measurable;  if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is measurable and $X$ is a random variable then  $f(X)$ is a random variable.